# Flink job failed, Caused by: java.io.IOException: The rpc invocation size exceeds the maximum akka framesize

Tags: apache-flink

Flink job failed,The error information is as follows

```
2020-12-02 09:37:27
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.submitTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.RpcTaskManagerGateway.submitTask(RpcTaskManagerGateway.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.lambda$deploy$9(Execution.java:735)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The rpc invocation size exceeds the maximum akka framesize.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.createRpcInvocationMessage(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:270)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.invokeRpc(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.invoke(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:129)
    ... 11 more
```

The logic of this job is simple,Consumption data of Kafka is saved to Clickhouse.

Start command

```sh
  flink run -m yarn-cluster -p 2 -ys 2 -yjm 2048 -ytm 2048 -ynm xx --class xx /data/flink/lib/xx.jar -name --input --groupId xx --bootstrapServers xx:9092 --CheckpointInterval 60000 --CheckpointTimeout 600000 --clientId xx
```

Why is that? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception means the payload of message(JM submits task to TM) exceeds max size. Try to increase the max size by adding `akka.framesize` to `flink-conf.yaml`.

The default for this is: 10485760b. Try to set a bigger number for this. Probably needing to restart the JM/TM or Flink cluster.

Doc: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/config.html#akka-framesize

Comment: what do we have to pay to increase it? anything we need to considering before increase it?

Comment: @RyanShao Flink uses AKKA for the internal communication among different services(Master/Executor/etc). AFAIK, AKKA in Flink uses Off-Heap memory, so pay attention to off-heap usage for task executors.